# Get calendar appointment from EWS exchange with jquery only

Tags: jquery, web-services, soap, soapui, exchangewebservices

I want to get calendar appointment from EWS exchange with jquery, I think I should use soap envelope in ajax jquery request. I tried a lot of syntax and nothing works because i can't find the correct xml request.
I tried to get it with SOAP ui, but soap ui doesn't accept this kind of web Service 
https://office.company.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
or
https://office.company.com/EWS/service.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP request format is shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx